# Prove that $|a - b| \le \Delta \implies |h(a) - h(b)| \le \Delta$

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value, epsilon-delta, upper-lower-bounds, entropy

For $0 \le a \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $0 \le b \le \frac{1}{2}$, does the following hold?

$$
|a - b| \le \Delta \implies |h(a) - h(b) | \le \Delta,
$$
where $h(x) = -x \log(x) - (1 - x) \log(1 - x)$ is the binary entropy function and $\Delta$ is a small quantity. I tried taking the lower bound of a binary entropy function like the following:
$$4x(1 - x) \le h(x) \le (4x(1 - x))^{(1/\ln(4))},$$ for both $a$ and $b$ but could not go anywhere.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend checking if the relation holds for $a = 0$ and $b > 0$.

Comment: $h'(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0$ so no.